# What is the relation of scattering, extinction and absorption cross sctions with scattering parameters?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering

In optics and electromagnetics, they frequently calculate the extinction, scattering or absorption cross sections of a **single** particle (e.g. a sphere). Scattering cross section which is the ratio of the amplitude of the scattered electric field to the incident electric field.

On the other hand, they also calculate the scattering parameters (or reflection and transmission coefficients) for an **array** of spheres, which is defined as the ratio of the transmitted energy to the incident energy.

My question is how are these two related to each other? (scattering cross section  and scattering parameters)

For example, we know that those extinction, scattering or absorption cross sections are far field parameters (right?). Now, are the scattering parameters based on far-field too?Or total field?

What is the relation between transmitted field and scattered field? Does a small transmittance mean a large scattering cross section or a small scattering cross section?